# Java integrated or embedded browser

Tags: java, browser, javafx-2

I need a integrated or embedded java browser. I used WebEngine of javafx which support basic css as well html & java script but could not able to run flash file. Any way to do so.

Or any other Project u know which could fulfill my requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check those (although they are not JavaFX but I suppose that they can be used):

1. http://lobobrowser.org/java-browser.jsp - pure Java
2. http://www.javadesktop.org/articles/jdic/index.html - better imho, but no longer maintained

Answer (score 3):

You can also look at [JxBrowser](http://www.teamdev.com/jxbrowser/) Java library that allows embedding Chromium-based web browser control into Java AWT/Swing application.

It supports both Java Swing and JavaFX.

BTW: the browser control is totally lightweight. All rendering happens in a separate native process by native Chromium engine. The web page looks like it's displayed in Google Chrome.